About downloading Ubuntu
If someone wants to install the free version of ubuntu in several systems or if he wants to install the deleted system again, he has to download once for each installation or can he do multiple installations with one download?

Ubuntu only has a free version. There is no paid version that you can download.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Ali! I hope you enjoy trying out Ubuntu as I did. Ubuntu is completely free of charge. You can download it as many times as you want, and you can install it as many times as you want.

@FedKad This is clearly a beginner, please remember what it was like to be a beginner yourself. Everyone has to learn this information for the first time at some point.

To the downvoters - this is someone who wants to use Ubuntu, has a legitimate question about it - why discourage? @Ali Zamani - welcome to Ask Ubuntu, hope you enjoy using Ubuntu.

It's free & open source software (FOSS), at least most of it is (there are some closed-source binaries in almost most Ubuntu ISO, such as Intel/AMD firmware updates; where those companies won't provide source code & only provide binary-blobs).  The free mostly relates to FREEDOM (you're free to use how you wish, even make changes, and give away to others too!) but even the NON-FREE code (binary blobs) are without cost you just don't have any freedom to change it.. but once downloaded you can install on as many boxes as you want.  You can also use zsync & other tools to update ISO.

Ubuntu is free software. There is no activation system or limit to the number of installations you can do of Ubuntu from any installation media.
Anyone stating there are restrictions is either unfamiliar with how Ubuntu works or is talking about Windows. Windows' restrictions on installation and activation don't apply to Ubuntu.

You can do any number of installs from one downloaded Ubuntu-image. You can 'burn' the image to any number of USB's and/or DVD's (or other installmedia). And each USB/DVD/Image can be installed on any number of systems.
There are no limits ...

I had heard a full Xubuntu is struggling to fit on a single DVD.

@quill ...that might be, but it is still free to download and can be legally installed on as many systems as you might wish.

The Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop download is 6GB, a bit hard to fit on 4.7GB media - i.e. out of the question; the DVD and CD-era is over, I never saw BR as a viable alternative to those. USB-flash, SSD or NVME is the way to go...
